# Eclipse:Unbound classpath container and nullpointer when adding a jre library

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I create a new java project in eclipse I get the "Red Exclamation mark of broken buildpaths". The official error from the problems log says "Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]' in project HelloWorld". My other android projects are functioning normally.

further examination has yielded:

  - the jre system library is unbound

  - any attempt to add a new system library returns a "null pointer exception" error in the add          library menu.

I have unsuccessfully attempted to remedy the problem by:

  - updating the jre and jdk.

  -trying to find the jre. the jre in mac is incredibly sneaky and all attempts to find it have failed.

  -Trying 1.6 instead of 1.7. same error on both.

I am using a macbook air with:

  -mac os

  -the latest java, jre and jdk

  -eclipse juno

  -pydev, android sdk, git and egit.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by going to Eclipse ->preferences-->java-->installed jre --> select a standard Vm in my case (Mac OSX) /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home.Finish

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: installed the eclipse java development plugin.The eclipse android sdk package didn't come with it.

Comment: how to install? Please advice